# Github Commit History Navigation

Tags: github

Is there a way to navigate forward and backward through the commit history on github?

I'd like something similar to Trac, where if I click on a specific changeset in the revision log, there are links for Next Change and Previous Change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most pages on GitHub support keyboard shortcuts. To see the shortcuts just press `?` on any GitHub page.

So, if you are looking at a particular commit, you will see several keyboard shortcuts available (under `Browsing Commits`) including: `p` for `parent commit`. So, when you are on a particular commit, press `p` and you will be taken to the previous (parent) commit. Unfortunately, I don't see a shortcut for navigating to the next (child) commit.

Also notice that all commit pages have links to the parent commits near the top of the page (look for the txt "1 parent" with a short SHA which will be a link to the parent commit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful. What I wasn't realizing is that git commits are a graph structure and not a linear sequence. While any commit should have a single parent, they may have multiple children.

Comment: They may also have multiple parents, typically two in the case of a merge. Github has `o` for "other parent commit". In the context of pull requests, there is `n` for "next commit" (child). I would really like it to be available outside of pull requests, since history is often linear.